# Python logging - config file in multiple modules with root logger

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, configuration-files

When i configure the root logger in a config file. the other children loggers don't follow the same configuration.

main.py

```
import logging
import logging.config
import test


logging.config.fileConfig("logger.ini")
logger = logging.root
logger.critical("main")
test.f()
```

test.py

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def f():
    print "inside f"
    logger.critical("Test")
    print logger.parent.name
    print logger.parent.handlers
```

logger.ini

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=console
[formatters]
keys=form
[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=console

[handler_console]
class=StreamHandler
formatter=form
args=()

[formatter_form]
format=%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s
```

when i run the program i don't have i got

```
CRITICAL:root:main
inside f
root
[<logging.StreamHandler object at 0x00000000021C4908>]
```

But i don't have the log from the other file.
I thought that if children don't have any handlers he will send the log to his parent. any idea why i don't see the log? or how to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What happens here is that the logger fetched in `test.py` is created before you call `logging.config.fileConfig("logger.ini")` in `main.py`. Once `fileConfig` is called, any pre-existing loggers not specified in the config file are deleted.

There are two ways I can suggest to solve this:

1. Do not call `logging.getLogger` in a module's global scope, but only when you need the logger inside a function / method
2. Change your code so when calling `fileConfig()`, you specify: `logging.config.fileConfig("logger.ini", disable_existing_loggers=False)`. This causes any loggers created before the configuration is applied to be maintained and not disabled.

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.fileConfig for details on option #2.

Comment: Thanks it worked fine. I prefer the second option. :D